# App has been unlisted from Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I had my app in the marketplace for around an year and recently found it was unlisted. I think it might be because one of the instances of the app was using the old API. I fixed it but found no way to inform Google so the listing could be activated again.

Today, I found that the listing has completely been deleted from the marketplace.

Can someone help sharing insights on what might have happened or what is the process to bring back the listing? Or perhaps how to reach out to someone at Google to help resolve this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Apps Marketplace V1 (GAM v1) is being deprecated, during this process the applications that were not migrated to the new version (GAM v2) were unlisted.

Here you can find information about the GAM v2 and how to publish your app in this new platform. https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/

One difference is that the new listing version runs under Chrome web store https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard

Comment: Thanks Gerardo! Do you have any idea if it is possible to bypass the Extensions option. I do not want my app on Universal navigation because it is not self-installable, nor do I need Drive integration or COB. Help!

Comment: That functionality is optional. In order to use any of those options you have to click on the check box to enable the functionality. As you don't need any of those options, just leave those extensions disabled.

Comment: Nope. Atleast one is mandatory. [See the screenshot](https://app.box.com/s/u09vhdz10j5o24856km1). Have you been able to submit an app without any of these extensions?

Comment: My bad, it is required. What do you mean by "it is not self-installable"? When a user installs the application, the app's icon is now present in the universal navigation so it can be accessible for the user.

Comment: The app is not automatically installed. I manually setup the code files and database and the configure the certain parameters for use with specific domain. I understand what you are saying about self-installable apps, but my app is not currently that way. I can do it, but that will mean some work, however, I wish to make the listing live asap and I can then continue working towards the goal of self-installable app. Thoughts?